# Clustered Dijkstra with negative weights

Tags: graph-theory

Let there be a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ and each vertex belongs to one of $k$ clusters. Each edge has a weight that can be negative, zero, or positive in value. How do I find the shortest distances between any two clusters?

Formally, for every pair of clusters $A$ and $B$, we wish to find:

$$ \min_{v_A \in A, v_B \in B} \text{dist}(v_A , v_B ).$$

The algorithm must run in time $O(k|E| \log(|V |)+ |V ||E|)$.

Assume Dijkstra's runs in $O(|E| \log(|V |)$ for each source vertex.

**Proposed solution**

We create a new vertex $v_i$ in each cluster $i$. $v_i$ is connected to all vertices in cluster $i$ with weight $0$. Use Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path to all other $v_j$ in cluster $j$. Repeat for each $v_j$. This yields an algorithm that runs in $O(k|E| \log(|V |)$.

However, it does not work with negative weights. How do I mitigate this? We can't use the Floyd-Warhshall nor the Bellman-Ford algorithms since they run in $O(|V|^3)$ and $O(|V|^2|E|)$ time.

**EDIT: BF running time**

Yes, the BF algorithm is actually $O(|V||E|)$ for one source vertex. But to find distances between all pairs of vertices, we will need to repeat the algorithm $|V|$ times, making the total runtime $O(|V|^2|E|)$

**EDIT: Directed**

The graph is a directed graph

Comment: Distance is the length of shortest path. What is "shortest distance"?

Comment: min dist($v_a, v_b$) would be the length of shortest path between $v_a$ and $v_b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I hope that the input graph is directed and has no negative cycles. Presence of negative cycles makes the problem either being NP-hard or having an answer $-\infty$, depending on exact definition of distance. An undirected graph with negative edge weights and without negative cycles is a correct input, however no simple algorithm like Dijkstra's, Bellman—Ford, Floyd—Warshall is applicable for it. So further we think that the graph has no negative cycles.

Your idea about creating additional vertices and counting distances between them is good and leads to a solution.

But you are wrong about the running time of the Bellman—Ford algorithm. It is $\mathrm O(|V|\cdot|E|)$. (And I have no idea about any slower version of this algorithm.) However you can use it only a constant number of times to satisfy the required asymptotic bound. (Spoiler: one time is enough.)

And you are also right that bound hints that Dijkstra's algorithm could be used $k$ times. So our goal is to make it applicable. For that reason we need to reweight the graph keeping the shortest path being the shortest path. Such a reweighting exists. The whole solution will be a variation of [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm). Here I briefly describe the idea, and all details you can find in materials about Johnson's algorithm, e. g., in [Introduction to algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

Let's consider a function $h\colon V \to \mathbb R$. We can reweight graph in the following way: $w'(u, v) = w(u, v) + h(u) - h(v)$. For any function $h$ such reweighting changes length of each $(u, v)$-path by $h(u) - h(v)$, because for every internal vertex $x$ of the path the value $h(x)$ is firstly subtracted and then added to the path length. This gives the property that the shortest $(u, v)$-path in the graph $G = (V, E, w)$ remains begin the shortest $(u, v)$-path in the reweighted graph $G' = (V, E, w')$.

So we only need such a function $h$ that all weights will become non-negative. And such a function can be found in the following way. Let's add a new vertex $v$ and zero weight arcs from $v$ to every vertex of the graph. It can't create a negative cycles, because it doesn't have an incoming arc. Now find the distances $d(v, u)$ from the vertex $v$ to all other vertices (all these distances are non-positive) using Bellman—Ford algorithm. Now consider $h(u) = d(v, u)$. One can prove that with such $h$ all $w'$ are non-negative. And now Dijkstra's algorithm is fairly applicable in the graph $G'$ giving you the shortest paths for the graph $G$ too.